# Understanding definition of properly discontinuous action

Tags: algebraic-topology

From Bredon, we say that the $G$-action on a space $X$ is properly discontinuous if

> "Each point $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $g(U) \cap U \neq \emptyset$" implies "$g = e$, an identity element of $G$".

But, if we take $U=X$, then $g(U)=U=X$ so any point in $X$ would have such neighborhood. I think that there is some problem in my understanding or the definition in the textbook is misleading.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Note: $\bigl(g(U)\cap U\neq \varnothing\bigr) \implies g = e$ means that for every $h\neq e$, we have $h(U) \cap U = \varnothing$. Unless $G$ is trivial, that is certainly not fulfilled if you choose $U = X$. You need to choose $U$ small for that.

Comment: Take $U=X$. Is it true that "$g(X) \cap X \ne \emptyset$ implies $g=e$"? Only if $G$ is the trivial group, otherwise any nontrivial element $g \in G$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Oh, OK. so the correct statement is "each pt $x \in X$ has nbd $U$" such that for any $g \neq e$ $g(U) \cap U = \emptyset$.

Comment: Which is the same as the given. $(g\neq e) \implies g(U)\cap U =\varnothing$ is the contrapositive of $\bigl(g(U)\cap U\neq \varnothing\bigr)\implies g = e$.

Comment: The point of my counterexampls is not that the statement is wrong, but that your logic is wrong. The statement says "Each point $x \in X$ **has** a neighborhood $U$ such that …". That does not allow you to choose $U$ to be whatever you might want it to be such as $U=X$.

Comment: Beware: what you call 'properly discontinuous' does not coincide with what some authors call properly discontinuous; they allow nontrivial stabilizers. I have seen the notion in your question been called 'totally discontinuous'.